# How to store local SQLite database on a server

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created an android application with an SQLite database. However, I did not realize this was stored locally. Is there any way to connect the locally distributed SQLite database on personal devices to a global DB Server?

I need the database to be synchronized across all devices.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with JSON. Do you mean convert the SQLite database to JSON and store on a server?

Comment: First upload all local SQLite data to server using web-service and one more web-service to upload data direct to server from next on-wards.

Comment: `Why not store it directly to the server`. That is a good question/remark.  `with JSON?`. Why json? What does it matter how! Irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, there are several ways to achieve this.

Basically what you'll want is an **API**, which exposes the basic **CRUD** operations on your database. Your devices then interact with the **API** and store the data directly on the server.

The next step would be allowing the devices to save the data **offline** and sync it as soon as the device gets online. In this scenario, you'll need a **local** **sqlite** *(or whatever)* **database** in order to keep track of what changed on the device.

I would recommend you to read some stuff out there about synchronizing databases on mobile devices. Offline as well as online. You can find a basic explanation in [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206310/data-synchronization-in-mobile-apps-multiple-devices-multiple-users) thread.